# Compare Month to last years Month total

Tags: powerbi, dax

In power Bi, I am creating a report that compares this years data to last years.  For example, I have January data for 2022 but I need to calculate all of the data for January in 2021.  In the pic, I have CY (current year) data for January.  The second matrix would display the Previous year data.  the data in the PY pic is not correct. Can someone help me figure out a dax formula for it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is going to depend on whether you have a date table in your model or not. But essentially, you need to change the filter context for the previous/last year measure using the `CALCULATE` function.

As an aside, I noticed your column names between the pictures were not really similar, i.e. *Sales Order* seems different than *Actual Shipping*. But in any case...

**With a date table**

```
PY Calculation = CALCULATE(
    SUM( YourTable[YourColumn] ), // or some other calculation...
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( DateTable[Date] )
)
```

**Without a date table**

```
PY Calculation = CALCULATE(
    SUM( YourTable[YourColumn] ), // or some other calculation...
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( YourTable[SomeDateColumn].[Date] )
)
```

Let me know if that worked for you. (And yes, there are other ways to accomplish the same thing.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  That measure works but it sums up all of the data for the previous year.  I want it to sum the data for the month we are currently in but the previous year.  For example, it is Jan, 2022, I want to sum data for Jan 2021.